# How to get geo data as a return from an ip on omegle?

Tags: javascript, api, ip, tracking, ice

1. Whenever I open a new Omegle video chat it returns me their IP when I run the code from the chrome console I was wondering how I can connect an API that automatically returns me the geo data along with the IP so I don't have to individually look it up.

```
window.oRTCPeerConnection  = window.oRTCPeerConnection || window.RTCPeerConnection

window.RTCPeerConnection = function(...args) {
 const pc = new window.oRTCPeerConnection(...args)

pc.oaddIceCandidate = pc.addIceCandidate

pc.addIceCandidate = function(iceCandidate, ...rest) {
 const fields = iceCandidate.candidate.split(' ')

if (fields[7] === 'srflx') {
console.log('IP Address:', fields[4])
}
return pc.oaddIceCandidate(iceCandidate, ...rest)

}

return pc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
window.oRTCPeerConnection = window.oRTCPeerConnection || window.RTCPeerConnection

window.RTCPeerConnection = function(...args) {
    const pc = new window.oRTCPeerConnection(...args)

    pc.oaddIceCandidate = pc.addIceCandidate

    pc.addIceCandidate = function(iceCandidate, ...rest) {
        const fields = iceCandidate.candidate.split(' ')

        if (fields[7] === 'srflx') {
            console.log('IP Address:', fields[4]);
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://ipinfo.io/" + fields[4] + "/json" , true); // true for asynchronous
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        return pc.oaddIceCandidate(iceCandidate, ...rest)
    }

    return pc
}
```

I included a GET for a JSON result that uses the field[4] IP from the script of the question. Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this API it returns a lot of geographic info about any IP, all you need to do is to give it the IP

http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/1.3.3.7

Just do a get request to this link and change 1.3.3.7 to any IP.

You can do a get request as following:

```
url = "http://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/" + fields[4]
function httpGet(Url)
{
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, false ); // false for synchronous request
   xmlHttp.send( null );
   return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
geographic_info = httpGet(url)
console.log(geographic_info)
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how i would add it to my script cuz thats what im having trouble getting it to work

Comment: I am not that much into JS so all I can help you is that you need to do a get request with the URL I gave you and replace the IP "1.3.3.7" with **field[4]** and then do console.log for the response that you will get

Answer (score 0):

Create a free account at https://ipinfo.io. You get 50,000 free requests per month. Then just parse the json like so:

```
const request = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://ipinfo.io/' + StrangerIpGoesHere + '? 
token=yourIpinfoTokenGoesHere');
  const data = await response.json();
  var strangerCity = data.city;
  var strangerState = data.region;
  var strangerCountry = data.country;
}
```